# Is Base64.DEFAULT adding linefeed to end of encoded string regardless string length ever an industry standard?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

According to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java

> Passing {@code DEFAULT} results in output that adheres to RFC 2045.

I thought by using `Base64.DEFAULT`, I can achieve a standard encoding behavior, which can easily found in other platforms.

### Java Android

```
    byte[] binary = new byte[80];
    String output = Base64.encodeToString(binary, Base64.DEFAULT);
    android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", unEscapeString(output));

    binary = new byte[8];
    output = Base64.encodeToString(binary, Base64.DEFAULT);
    android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", unEscapeString(output));

public static String unEscapeString(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        switch (s.charAt(i)){
            case '\n': sb.append("\\n"); break;
            case '\t': sb.append("\\t"); break;
            case '\r': sb.append("\\r"); break;
            default: sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    return "\"" + sb.toString() + "\"";
}
```

I will getting the following output from Android Java.

```
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=\n"
"AAAAAAAAAAA=\n"
```

---

It seems for `Base64.DEFAULT`, it has behavior

1. Adding line feed ('\n') after 76th characters.
2. Adding line feed ('\n') at end of encoded string.

As, my iOS app need to exchange data from Android app. I notice that I can simulate 1st behavior (Adding line feed ('\n') after 76th characters).

But, not 2nd behavior (Adding line feed ('\n') at end of encoded string)

---

### Swift iOS

```
import Foundation

var data = Data(count: 80)
var base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: [.endLineWithLineFeed, .lineLength76Characters])
debugPrint(base64)

data = Data(count: 8)
base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: [.endLineWithLineFeed, .lineLength76Characters])
debugPrint(base64)
```

I get the following output from Swift iOS.

```
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="
"AAAAAAAAAAA="
```

---

This makes me think, is adding linefeed to end of encoded string regardless string length ever an industry standard? How can I achieve that behavior across different platforms?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Android's default base64 encoding automatically inserts linebreaks/linefeeds after the 76th character in each line.

You can disable this "feature" by using Android's `Base64.NODE_WRAP` mode. For example: `Base64.encodeToString(binary, Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Why does this happen? No one seems to know for sure, but it's likely that it was a way to encode binary files into email or usenet-style content, which was generally formatted for 80-character width monitors back in the plain-text days.

See [man_base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) for some hint of this.